# How can i use the modules written for Frama-C' s plugin?

Tags: frama-c

**Build** is a module which has been developed in order to build the PDG.
I wrote a script which uses this module **Build** but when i try to launch this script with:

## frama-c -load-script test.ml

I get the mistake: Unbound module Build.
Is there a way to get access to this module. I need it in my project.
**Build** is an example but there are another modules like **Sets** which provides functions to read a PDG. However, others modules like **PdgTypes** don't make mistakes. If anybody could help me...

In my file test.ml,
let compute = Build.compute_pdg
....

let () = Db.Main.extend main

Comment: Did you register your ``Build`` module as a Frama-C plug-in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. `-load-script` can only work for script that do not have any dependency outside of Frama-C (or Frama-C's own dependencies such as OCamlgraph). As suggested by Anne, if your code is contained in more than one file, you should write it as a plugin.

For a simple plugin, you basically only have to write a short `Makefile` in addition to your OCaml code. This `Makefile` will mainly contain the list of source files of your plugin and a few additional information (such as the plugin's name), as explained in [the developer's manual](http://frama-c.com/download/frama-c-plugin-development-guide.pdf), which contain a small tutorial.

Alternatively, if you have only two files, it should be possible to assemble them manually into a single module that can then be loaded by Frama-C. Supposing you have `build.ml` and `test.ml`, you could do (with the Sodium
version)

```
ocamlopt -I $(frama-c-config -print-libpath) -c build.ml
ocamlopt -I $(frama-c-config -print-libpath) -c test.ml
ocamlopt -shared -o script.cmxs build.cmx test.cmx
frama-c -load-module script.cmxs [other options] [files]
```

Comment: Thank you for yours prompt answers! I thought a bit about the Makefile but i was wondering if there was not another way. Effectively, this is a script which has a dependency outside of Frama-C

Answer (score 3):

The modules you refer to, `Build` and `Sets`, are not considered as being part of the public user interface of Frama-C. Instead, they are internal to the plugin `PDG`. The modules of `PDG` you can access from user scripts are those in the directory `src/pdgTypes`: `PdgIndex`, `PdgMarks` and `PdgTypes`. Then, a second part of the API is available inside `Db.Pdg` (`Db` is in `src/kernel/db.ml`). In particular, most of the functions of the module `Sets` are re-exported there.

For the functions available inside `Build`, they have been deemed too low-level to be exported. If you really need to access it, you will have to copy the directory `src/pdg` and transform it into a plugin (with a new name, to avoid clashes).

Comment: +1 @Boris: I read the question too fast, and I didn't realize that it was the PDG ``Build`` module, and thought it was from @Kune.